# Recursive function in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, recursion

I have nested dicts like this where keys are functions `{'Foo1': {'Foo2': {'value1': 0}, 'Foo3': {'value2': 1, 'value3': 1}}}`

I want to write a recursive function which has to calculate a final value. In this case it will be:

```
final_value = Foo1(Foo2(0), Foo3(1,1))
```

I will be very pleased if someone help me with advice.

Comment: Can you post the actual example of your dictionary wit keys as functions?

Comment: Since dictionaries are _unordered_, your `final value` might as well be `Foo1(Foo3(1,1), Foo2(0))` - which could be something completely different.

Comment: Thank you for a remark, but the order is not important here.

Comment: It might be as you have wrote. The final_value won't change @ChristianKönig

Comment: @AmeyDahale for example: dct = {'any': {'none': {'value1': 0}, 'all': {'value2': 1, 'value3': 1}}}

Comment: As you said keys are functions, so can you post an example of a dictionary where keys are functions? Your example is not quite clear.

Comment: Sorry, I meant names of functions. For example, if it is "ANY", a program will return any([some list]). If it's "NONE", the program will return not([some_value])

Comment: How do you distinguish that `Foo` is a function but `value` is a parameter to another function? Do you have a list of all whitelisted function names? Do functions have to start with a capital letter? Something else?

Comment: @supersam654 there are only four names of function: "any", "all", "sum" and "none". Values might be named without limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular case, I recommend using an explicit whitelist of allowed function names which map to functions in Python (see `WHITELIST` in the code below). This mitigates lots of potentially nasty security issues if you're trying to parse untrusted data. It also deals with your `"none"` requirement which doesn't map to a real function in Python.

The important part of the code is the `parse` function. It recursively walks through your input data and classifies every key as a function or a variable name. If it's a function, it calls that function with that key's value. Otherwise, it just uses the value. Either way, this info gets saved to `results` which gets recursively passed to the caller.

Note that this implementation doesn't even begin to attempt to deal with malformed input. I strongly recommend wrapping `parse` in a `try ... catch` block to gracefully deal with bad input.

```
data = {
    'any': {
        'none': {'value1': 0},
        'sum': {'value2': 0, 'value3': 1}
    }
}

# This can be expanded to include other functions that aren't built-in.
# Note that "none" is special because "not" isn't actually a function.
WHITELIST = {
    "any": any,
    "all": all,
    "sum": sum,
    "none": lambda x: not x
    "10": is_10 # Sample additional function you could add.
}

def is_10(values):
    return sum(values) == 10

def parse(data):
    results = []
    # Uncomment the next line if you're on Python 2.
    # for key, value in d.iteritems():
    # Leave this line if you're on Python 3.
    for key, value in data.items():
        if key in WHITELIST:
            # This is a function.
            function = WHITELIST[key]
            args = parse(value)
            results.append(function(args))
        else:
            # This is a value, so the name doesn't actually matter.
            results.append(value)
    return results

print(parse(data))
```

For the example at the top of the code, it prints`[True]` because their is a single function at the root of the data. If your data always has a single root function, you probably want to call parse as `output = parse(data)[0]`.

Comment: Thank you! "None" doesn't work with lists (not([0]) returns False, but should return True), but I'll fix it.